#  Convert Map to QueryString

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, hashmap, query-string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert map to url query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809877/how-to-convert-map-to-url-query-string)

How to convert Map to query string?

For example:

```
    MockHttpServletRequest request = getRequest();
    HashMap<String, String> queryString = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryString.put("IDcontent", "4546446");
    queryString.put("ID_CP", "604204d6-3ded-4882-9427-52f1ff8ee6c8");
    request.setQueryString(mapToQueryString(queryString));
```

I think that is this(mapToQueryString) to do standart library, but I can't find it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809877/how-to-convert-map-to-url-query-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define a method mapToueryString by yourself as:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(HashMap.Entry<String, String> e : queryString.entrySet()){
      if(sb.length() > 0){
          sb.append('&');
      }
      sb.append(URLEncoder.encode(e.getKey(), "UTF-8")).append('=').append(URLEncoder.encode(e.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
  }
```

Comment: this does not append a '?' at the beginning, and appends a '&' at the beginning instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
public String mapToQueryString(Map<String, String> map) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();

    if(map.size() > 0) {
        string.append("?");
    }

    for(Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        string.append(entry.getKey());
        string.append("=");
        string.append(entry.getValue());
        string.append("&");
    }

    return string.toString();
}
```

or use `URLEncodeUtils.format()` with `Collections2.transform(paramMap.entrySet(), function)` to transform.

Comment: Can you show an example by using URLEncoddeUtils.format()?

Comment: Wouldn't this append an "&" in the end of the string always?

Comment: @AshwinKrishnamurthy, I submitted an edit to fix the problem you note