# Grabbing partial data from URL in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In selenium, is there a way to grab partial dynamically changing data from a URL? Example, I ran driver.getCurrentUrl() in my code and retrieved the below URL. I only want to grab the numeric portion of it and concatenate it so I end up with 819499-1. However, next time I run it the values will be different. Is there a way to capture this information without capturing the entire URL?

http://custmaint/clnt_estimate_overview.jsp?estimateNbr=819499&versionNbr=1&estimateMgmt=true&clntAutoAssign=true

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a more generic question, not only related to Selenium...

Basically, You could use regular expression matching like so:

```
String url = "http://custmaint/clnt_estimate_overview.jsp?estimateNbr=819499&versionNbr=1&estimateMgmt=true&clntAutoAssign=true";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*\\?estimateNbr=(\\d+)&versionNbr=(\\d+).*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.group(1) + "-" + m.group(2));
}
```

Another approach (more flexible) is to use a dedicated library like httpcomponents; see [How to convert map to url query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809877/how-to-convert-map-to-url-query-string/37744000#37744000)

Comment: Pattern `estimateNbr=(\d+).*versionNbr=(\d+)`should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String estimateNbr = url.substring(url.indexOf("eNbr=")+5, url.indexOf("&v"));
String versionNbr = url.substring(url.indexOf("nNbr=")+5, url.indexOf("&e"));
System.out.println(estimateNbr + "-" + versionNbr);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I was trying to avoid regex.