# Standard Java Class for common URL/URI manipulation

Tags: java

This question has almost certainly been asked before, but I ask it anyway because I couldn't find an answer.

Generally, is there a utility class of some sort that assists in common String manipulations associated with URL/URIs?

I'm thinking something like Java SE's [URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) Class, but maybe a little beefier. I'm looking for something that will let you do simple things, like:

- Get a List of query string parameters
- An "addParameter" method to add a
  query string parameter, and it will
  take care of adding "&", "?", and "="
  where necessary
- Also, encoding
  parameter values would be ideal...

Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Good question. I couldn't find a good one so rolled my own. I'd like to see the suggestions here.

Comment: It is a well-known and much-complained-about lacuna that there is nothing in Java SE that can do anything interesting with query strings. For everything else, there's java.net.URI, which i would suggest be preferred to java.net.URL, because, amongst other things, it has a sane equals() implementation.

Comment: check out Galimatias - a URL parsing and normalization library written in Java https://github.com/smola/galimatias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't really (oddly enough) any standard that does it all. There are some bits and pieces, usually buried in various **util** packages:

I've used http://java.net/projects/urlencodedquerystring/pages/Home to decent effect (for extraction of parameters).

Atlassian's JIRA has http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/4.2/index.html?com/atlassian/jira/util/UrlBuilder.html, which I've actually extracted from the jar and used.

On Android, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html is a Uri builder that works pretty well as far as building a url with ease.

And finally, in a classic case of history repeating itself: [A good library to do URL Query String manipulation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218608/a-good-library-to-do-url-manipulation-in-java).

I'd really just rip out the android.net.Uri.Builder class and pair that with the urlencodedquerystring class and then carry those around with you, but this does seem like a good candidate for an Apache commons package.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the great reply! I've run into similar code in some various proprietary libraries before as well, which is what sparked this question. I think I'll take a stab at your suggestion! I'll leave this question open for a little while longer to see if I get any additional replies.

Comment: Accepting this answer. Additionally, Tom Anderson's comment on the main question was helpful as well.

Comment: Here's another question that has a suggestion for creating a url encoded query string from a Map. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809877/how-to-convert-map-to-url-query-string/2810102#2810434

Comment: This has also been discussed on the Guava issues page http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1005 They havent currently implemented there own library but someone suggests using the UriBuilder provided by Jersey

Comment: The Apache http components also come with a [URI builder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html). Unfortunately it is in the http client rather than in the http core module, which I would have expected.

Comment: I'd add that the OkHttp library comes with a [HttpUrl](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.html) class which allows you to construct and manipulate URL's. Easy to use and works well, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly like [UriBuilder](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) from jax-rs

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer OP's question directly (*i.e.* it's not a generic, all-around library for URL manipulation), **but**: if you're going to be using Spring anyway, you might as well consider the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` and `UriComponentsBuilder` classes (see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html) and [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html) for javadocs).

I believe they are bundled with the `spring-web` dependency. IMHO, these offer quite a few convenient utility methods for working with URIs, URLs and query parameters.