# How to fetch the values present in a url from a webview in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a url where there are ids (such as order id, product id, etc) in a webview. How can I fetch these ids and put them into strings?
Say for example, the url is

> www.xyz.com/buy/thankyou/handlers/display.html?ie=UTF8&asins=B00F0G8K&orderId=404-35644-70307&purchaseId=404-2849-9658

I need the values present for `&asins`, `&orderid`, `&purchase_id` and pass them to another url. How can I fetch them?
All of this is happening inside a webview.

Comment: Use `webView.getUrl()` and then a regex to extract the values.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. help me with the regex thing also please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the URL from `WebView`, parse it as `Uri` and get individual query parameters from it.

**Example:**

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(myWebView.getUrl());
String orderId = uri.getQueryParameter("orderid");
```

Comment: should i put this inside shouldOverrideUrlLoading()?

Comment: No, use this anytime you want to read the current URL of WebView. Just make sure that the URL is loaded.

Comment: best answer, simple and direct.

Answer (score 0):

> Just saw the answer by @rax, it is probably better.

Try something like this:

```
String regex = "asins=(.*)&orderId=(.*)&purchaseId=(.*)";
String myString = "www.xyz.com/buy/thankyou/handlers/display.html?ie=UTF8&asins=B00F0G8K&orderId=404-35644-70307&purchaseId=404-2849-9658 ";
//use String myString = webView.getUrl(); in your case;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll(regex, "$1"));
        System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll(regex, "$2"));
        System.out.println(matcher.group().replaceAll(regex, "$3"));
    }
```

Output:

```
B00F0G8K
404-35644-70307
404-2849-9658
```

Hope this helps, and do comment if you have any questions.

Comment: One more doubt Jonas, How to get multiple ids? ie, if there are multiple orderids, how to fetch it? Also, How to reload the ids to another URL?

Comment: @arv, In that case, try the answer by rax, or update your question with an example of a URL string you want to get the order ids from, and I will update my answer.

Comment: Okay, Consider the url in the above question as 1st url. 
The 2nd url is : http://sndbx.abc.com/mob#?path=confirmOrder&oid= &pid= &asins=  . 
Here the values of the orderid(multiple) from the first url should be filled here in the 2nd url ie, 2nd url should be http://sndbx.abc.com/mob#?path=confirmOrder&oid=404-35644-70307&pid=404-2849-9658 &asins=B00F0G8K

Comment: @arv, I will have a look.

Comment: @arv, will probably be a few hours, as i have other stuff to do.

Comment: @arv, sorry for taking so long, as i'm _very_ busy today, did you try the answer by rax ? Otherwise, you can do it with a separate regex. If you want an answer faster, ask a new question, and tag it with "regex".

Comment: oh :(   
I tried it, but i'm not getting the ids. Its not working. I checked it with LogCat.

Comment: @arv, Could you edit some example url's into your question, as the comment system seems to  have mangled the one you posted.

Comment: @arv, you could also use `String.split()`, as per [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13691481/4428462).

Comment: Ya okay.. Got it Jonas. Thanks ! I used rax's answer.

Comment: How to reload the 2nd url in the webview?

Comment: @arv, you can use `webview.reload()`