# How can I append a query parameter to an existing URL?

Tags: java, url

I'd like to append key-value pair as a query parameter to an existing URL. While I could do this by checking for the existence of whether the URL has a query part or a fragment part and doing the append by jumping though a bunch of if-clauses but I was wondering if there was clean way if doing this through the Apache Commons libraries or something equivalent.

`http://example.com` would be `http://example.com?name=John`

`http://example.com#fragment` would be `http://example.com?name=John#fragment`

`http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com` would be `http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com&name=John`

`http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com#fragment` would be `http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com&name=John#fragment`

I've run this scenario many times before and I'd like to do this without breaking the URL in any way.

Comment: Related: [A good library to do URL Query String manipulation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218608)

Comment: @Mridang Agarwalla Does my answer solve your problem? Let me know if you require any more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way to compose a URL or URI in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/883136/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-compose-a-url-or-uri-in-java)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This can be done by using the [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class to construct a new instance using the parts from an existing one, this should ensure it conforms to URI syntax.

The query part will either be null or an existing string, so you can decide to append another parameter with & or start a new query.

```
public class StackOverflow26177749 {

    public static URI appendUri(String uri, String appendQuery) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI oldUri = new URI(uri);

        String newQuery = oldUri.getQuery();
        if (newQuery == null) {
            newQuery = appendQuery;
        } else {
            newQuery += "&" + appendQuery;  
        }

        return new URI(oldUri.getScheme(), oldUri.getAuthority(),
                oldUri.getPath(), newQuery, oldUri.getFragment());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(appendUri("http://example.com", "name=John"));
        System.out.println(appendUri("http://example.com#fragment", "name=John"));
        System.out.println(appendUri("http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com", "name=John"));
        System.out.println(appendUri("http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com#fragment", "name=John"));
    }
}
```

Shorter alternative

```
public static URI appendUri(String uri, String appendQuery) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI oldUri = new URI(uri);
    return new URI(oldUri.getScheme(), oldUri.getAuthority(), oldUri.getPath(),
            oldUri.getQuery() == null ? appendQuery : oldUri.getQuery() + "&" + appendQuery, oldUri.getFragment());
}
```

Output

```
http://example.com?name=John
http://example.com?name=John#fragment
http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com&name=John
http://example.com?email=john.doe@email.com&name=John#fragment
```

Comment: @Charlie Correct a ternary would reduce line count, but may also reduce readability

Comment: It eliminates some variables too which means less complexity.

Comment: @Charlie I've added alternative to my answer with ternary.

Comment: Even simpler, don't bother pulling out the bits, you really just need to know if you should use a ? or a &, which the ternary would do: return uri + new URI(uri).getQuery() == null ? "?" : "&" + appendQuery;

Comment: Here it is assumed that `appendQuery` is escaped properly and not called like: `uri = appendUri(uri, "foo=" + bar)`.  I'd strongly prefer an API with distinct `name` and `value` parameters and then have the escaping done *inside* `appendQuery`

Comment: Downvote because it is insecure. String concatenation is vulnerable to parameter injection as the added value is not encoded.

Comment: If the URL already has the query param, it just appends a new one with the same name. Not very helpful.

Answer (score 242):

There are plenty of libraries that can help you with URI building (don't reinvent the wheel). Here are three to get you started:

---

#### [Java EE 7](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax%7Cjavaee-api%7C7.0%7Cjar)

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
...
return UriBuilder.fromUri(url).queryParam(key, value).build();
```

---

#### [org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.httpcomponents%7Chttpclient%7C4.5.2%7Cjar)

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
...
return new URIBuilder(url).addParameter(key, value).build();
```

---

#### [org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.5.RELEASE](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-web%7C4.2.5.RELEASE%7Cjar)

```
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;
...
return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).queryParam(key, value).build().toUri();
```

---

**See also:** [GIST > URI Builder Tests](https://gist.github.com/nickgrealy/b4f35bf5e5e5a444aff20c4616b51513)

Comment: Regarding spring's builder. `build().toUri()` will not produce a correct URI, if `key` or `value` need encoding. Don't forget to manually encode them. It's also better to use `build(true).toUri()` for validation. Don't `.build().encode().toUri()`, or `build(false).encode()`, or `build(Map)` or `.toUriString()` directly. Latter 2 are a shortcut for `.build(false).encode().toUri()`. The reason to not use them in this case, is because if the original URL already contained URL encoded parts (including query string), `.build().encode()` will encode them again, resulting in a broken URL.

Answer (score 7):

For android, Use:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri#buildUpon()

```
URI oldUri = new URI(uri);
Uri.Builder builder = oldUri.buildUpon();
 builder.appendQueryParameter("newParameter", "dummyvalue");
 Uri newUri =  builder.build();
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was especting, thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class.

Create a new `URI` with your existing `String` to "break it up" to parts, and instantiate another one to assemble the modified url:

```
URI u = new URI("http://example.com?email=john@email.com&name=John#fragment");

// Modify the query: append your new parameter
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(u.getQuery() == null ? "" : u.getQuery());
if (sb.length() > 0)
    sb.append('&');
sb.append(URLEncoder.encode("paramName", "UTF-8"));
sb.append('=');
sb.append(URLEncoder.encode("paramValue", "UTF-8"));

// Build the new url with the modified query:
URI u2 = new URI(u.getScheme(), u.getAuthority(), u.getPath(),
    sb.toString(), u.getFragment());
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest an improvement of the Adam's answer accepting HashMap as parameter

```
/**
 * Append parameters to given url
 * @param url
 * @param parameters
 * @return new String url with given parameters
 * @throws URISyntaxException
 */
public static String appendToUrl(String url, HashMap<String, String> parameters) throws URISyntaxException
{
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    String query = uri.getQuery();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    if (query != null)
        builder.append(query);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: parameters.entrySet())
    {
        String keyValueParam = entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue();
        if (!builder.toString().isEmpty())
            builder.append("&");

        builder.append(keyValueParam);
    }

    URI newUri = new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getAuthority(), uri.getPath(), builder.toString(), uri.getFragment());
    return newUri.toString();
}
```

Comment: WARNING: Escape all components of `parameters` properly. Imagine I came with a value like `foo&bar=45`...

Answer (score 2):

For Android, use this function to append a new parameter to your existing URI.

**Java**

```java
private Uri appendUriParameter(Uri uri, String key, String newValue) {
  final Set<String> params = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
  final Uri.Builder newUri = uri.buildUpon().clearQuery();
  for (String param : params) {
    newUri.appendQueryParameter(param, uri.getQueryParameter(param));
  }
  newUri.appendQueryParameter(key, newValue);

  return newUri.build();
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
private fun appendUriParameter(uri: Uri, key: String, newValue: String) {
    val params = uri.queryParameterNames()
    val newUri = uri.buildUpon().clearQuery()
    for (param in params) {
        newUri.appendQueryParameter(param, uri.queryParameter(param))
    }
    return newUri.appendQueryParameter(key, newValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin & clean, so you don't have to refactor before code review:

```
private fun addQueryParameters(url: String?): String? {
        val uri = URI(url)

        val queryParams = StringBuilder(uri.query.orEmpty())
        if (queryParams.isNotEmpty())
            queryParams.append('&')

        queryParams.append(URLEncoder.encode("$QUERY_PARAM=$param", Xml.Encoding.UTF_8.name))
        return URI(uri.scheme, uri.authority, uri.path, queryParams.toString(), uri.fragment).toString()
    }
```

Comment: A little bit late, but anyway. Try not to encode the equals symbol. Otherwise it may be problematic by clients to understand the keys and the values

Comment: Why should we encode params? It will throw: 'java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: UTF_8'.

Comment: `queryParams` end up being encoded improperly

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda and [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html), code can be more concise:

```
public static URI appendUri(String url, Map<String, String> parameters) throws URISyntaxException {
    final var uri = new URI(url);
    final var sj = new StringJoiner("&");

    parameters.forEach((name, value) -> sj.add(name + "=" + value));
    final var query = uri.getQuery() == null ? sj.toString() : sj.length() > 0 ? uri.getQuery() + "&" + sj : uri.getQuery();

    return new URI(uri.getScheme(), uri.getUserInfo(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getPath(), query, uri.getFragment());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An update to Adam's answer considering tryp's answer too. Don't have to instantiate a String in the loop.

```
public static URI appendUri(String uri, Map<String, String> parameters) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI oldUri = new URI(uri);
    StringBuilder queries = new StringBuilder();

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> query: parameters.entrySet()) {
        queries.append( "&" + query.getKey()+"="+query.getValue());
    }

    String newQuery = oldUri.getQuery();
    if (newQuery == null) {
        newQuery = queries.substring(1);
    } else {
        newQuery += queries.toString();
    }

    URI newUri = new URI(oldUri.getScheme(), oldUri.getAuthority(),
            oldUri.getPath(), newQuery, oldUri.getFragment());

    return newUri;
}
```