# How to retrieve specific values from String

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am working on something that enforces me to clean a `String` value by retrieving only some specific `substring` values.

The `String` follows the following pattern:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&param5=value5
```

I need a solution that retrieves the appropriate values `{value1, value2, value3}`.

Is there anything ready for this purpose in `commans-lang3`?

Comment: You could split the string on & and = and then process the bits however you want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A good library to do URL Query String manipulation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218608/a-good-library-to-do-url-query-string-manipulation-in-java)

Comment: To add on to Robin, once you finish splitting, call them by their index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you may split on `&` then on `=` , like this example :

```
String testString = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&param4=value4&param5=value5";

String[] paramValues = testString.split("\\&");

for (String paramValue : paramValues) {

    System.out.println(paramValue.split("\\=")[1]);
}
```